# Wordpress Multisite allow site admin to add user without email confirmation

Tags: multisite, admin, users

In Wordpress Multisite,a site admin (not a super admin) doesn't have the option “Add the user without sending them a confirmation email” when adding a new user.
Is there a way to bypass the confirmation email or to add this option also for site admin ?
Many thanks

Comment: On a past proiect, I removed the original add-user page and I've added a custom one with custom hooks and processing. I will return with a code snippet if you want to go this way.

Answer (score 3):

You will not be able to enable the checkbox for non-super-admins as the code for it shows:

```
<?php if ( is_multisite() && is_super_admin() ) { ?>
<tr>
    <th scope="row"><label for="noconfirmation"><?php _e('Skip Confirmation Email') ?></label></th>
    <td><label for="noconfirmation"><input type="checkbox" name="noconfirmation" id="noconfirmation" value="1" <?php checked( $new_user_ignore_pass ); ?> /> <?php _e( 'Add the user without sending them a confirmation email.' ); ?></label></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

You can disable the sending of the confirmation emails altogether with the following:

```
add_filter( 'wpmu_welcome_user_notification', '__return_false');
```

The other option is create a plugin that makes your own custom add user page.

Answer (score 2):

It's now possible in recent version of Wordpress ([since 3.8](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-enable-skip-confirmation-email-checkbox-for-individual-site-admins) ?), with the right "manage_network_users".

You can access it with the [User Role editor](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/) plug-in, for example (in network admin prefs).