# Give to site admin the option to "skip confirmation email" when adding new user

Tags: multisite, users, email-verification

in wordpress multisite when we give to site admin the option to add new users, site admin dont have the "checkbox" to add the new user without sending the user email with link activation (see the screenshot)

[image]

how can we add this option to site admin?

Comment: no one knows how to make this?

Comment: It's possible since 3.8. See my answer there : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/125488/wordpress-multisite-allow-site-admin-to-add-user-without-email-confirmation/222644

Comment: there is already a checkbox when an admin creates a new user that says "Send the new user an email about their account." which accomplishes the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Paste this in your `functions.php` file:

```
function my_skip_confirmation_email() {
    if ( is_multisite() && current_user_can( 'create_users' ) ) { ?>

    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th scope="row"><?php _e( 'Skip Confirmation Email' ); ?></th>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="noconfirmation" id="noconfirmation" value="1" />
                <label for="noconfirmation"><?php _e( 'Add the user without sending an email that requires their confirmation.' ); ?></label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php }
}
add_action( 'user_new_form', 'my_skip_confirmation_email' );
```

Comment: Please explain how this code works.

Comment: All this does is add a checkbox that SAYS to add the user and bypass the confirmation email, but it doesn't actually achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your funcitons.php file

```
    function skp_custom_user_create_fields($user){
    if (!is_super_admin( $user_id )) {
?>

    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th scope="row"><?php _e('Skip Confirmation Email') ?></th>
            <td><input type = "checkbox" name = "noconfirmation" value = "1" <?php checked( $_POST['noconfirmation'], 1 ); ?> /> Add the user without sending an email that requires their confirmation.</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php
    }
}
add_action("user_new_form", "skp_custom_user_create_fields");

function skp_auto_activate_users($user, $user_email, $key, $meta){

    if(!current_user_can('manage_options'))
        return false;

    if (!empty($_POST['noconfirmation']) && $_POST['noconfirmation'] == 1) {
        wpmu_activate_signup($key);
          return false;
    }
}
add_filter('wpmu_signup_user_notification', 'skp_auto_activate_users', 10, 4);
```

That would do the job.